# Get the text after specific word for substring c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have following values:

```
<H2:H2LabelComboBoxCell ID="LabelComboboxCellProject"  SecurityID="CD4D3959-0ADB-4375-8DCF-917157528BDE" MaxLength=100/>
<H2:H2LabelFileListCell ID="LabelFileListCellApplicationAttachched" ColumnSpan="1" DataSource="ClientFileH2BindingSource" />
<H2:H2LabelTextBoxCell LabelText="Budget (€)" ColumnSpan="1" ID="LabelTextboxCellBudget" />
<H2W:H2CheckBoxList ID= "H2CheckBoxListReasonForRejection" DataIsDefaultMember="IsDefault" runat="server" />
```

I need to get value of ID in each row.

I thought of use substring as follows:

```
string line= @"<H2:H2LabelComboBoxCell ID="LabelComboboxCellProject"  SecurityID="CD4D3959-0ADB-4375-8DCF-917157528BDE"/>"
string id= line.Substring(line.IndexOf("ID="),xyz);
```

How can i get the value of ID ( value i can use for xyz)

**EDIT :**
I tried this with `XmlDocument` as Foolows:

```
string text= " <H2H2LabelTextBoxCell ID="H2LabelTextBoxCell1" runat="server" TextSize=400 PlaceHolder="" LabelText="Translate into" Token="Translation_Into_For_Language_management_Initial" DataSource="SelectedTokensForStaticListTypeBindingSource2" DataMember="Value" Disabled="False" SecurityID="755C974E-211A-4832-B5E2-F3765194E6BC"></H2H2LabelTextBoxCell> "
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.LoadXml(text);
```

this throws following exception :
'400' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 1, position 72.

Due to formatting issues i move back to normal line reading option.

Comment: This looks like XML - wouldn't it be easier to treat it as such?

Comment: @germi can't treat it like XML, because this value contain maxLength=100   sort of values

Comment: why do you want to knwo the ID's, and is the code yours? And 100 maxlenght of value is oke to treat as xml

Comment: @lordkain i tried with `XmlDocument` but it says can't load file because it contain numeric values. nned to use either " " or ' '

Comment: Cant you just extract it with regex?

Comment: you can use the HTML Agility pack for html.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack Sounds better for youre problem tyhen working with substring

Comment: This example gives what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462552/get-all-attribute-values-of-given-tag-with-html-agility-pack

Comment: Hi,  for html documents, you could follow this,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253947/how-can-i-get-values-from-html-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incase you don't want to do the whole XML thing.

```
private static int Main(string[] args)
{
    string line= "<H2:H2LabelComboBoxCell ID=\"LabelComboboxCellProject\"  SecurityID=\"CD4D3959-0ADB-4375-8DCF-917157528BDE\"/>";

    string stringToFind = "ID=\"";
    int firstQuote = line.IndexOf(stringToFind) + stringToFind.Length;
    int nextQuote  = line.IndexOf("\"",firstQuote);

    string id= line.Substring(firstQuote,nextQuote-firstQuote);

    System.Console.Write("id="+id);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
int start, end;
start = line.IndexOf("ID=\"") + ("ID=\"").Length;
end = line.IndexOf("\"", start);
string id= line.Substring(start,end-start);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also using [Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) as well.